# How to show time in addition to date in Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization

My time-series-style Google Chart (`google.visualization.DataTable`) isn't showing times in the x-axis; only the dates.

How do I get it to show time increments on the X-axis?  I understand how to update the formatter to show times, but there's no x-axis values in the first place, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: may I see your column 0 data ?